Certificate is not accessible to the current user
Receiving the above error while connecting to exchange online through system center orchestrator runbook workflow. The path given was verified and correct. The script works completely fine when we run in ISE.
The same script works completely fine in powershell ISE. When it comes to SCORCH, it works well in run book tester but not through workflow.

$tenant =‘xxxxxx’
$appid =‘xxxx’
$certpath =‘H:/Exchange cert/exchange online connection.pfx’
$pfxpassword =‘xxxxxx’
Connect-Exchangeonline
-CertificateFilePath $certpath
-CertificatePassword (ConvertTo-Securestring -string $pfxpassword -AsPlainText -force)
-Appid $appid
-Organization $tenant
-ErrorAction ‘stop’

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
